# How can I tell IntelliJ that a Kotlin module/project is NOT multiplatform and also tell it to use JVM 11?

Tags: kotlin, gradle, intellij-idea

It's a Kotlin Gradle+Kotlin project. Project is shown as multiplatform, but I don't care about mobile. This will run on a JVM in a Docker container.

I tried

```
java.sourceCompatibility = JavaVersion.VERSION_11
```

in the build.gradle.kts, IntelliJ doesn't seem to pick it up.

Thanks.

**EDIT: more details**

It's the latest version of IntelliJ.
I have on my machine the following JDKs: 8, 11, 13, 15, 16

Comment: Can you define "_it doesn't seem to work_"?

Comment: Despite having this line in the build.gradle.kts file, IntelliJ doesn't pick it up. I don't know how IntelliJ decides which version of Java to use, but it doesn't seem to read it from the build.gradle.kts